How to add authentication ability to Swagger/OpenAPI in Symfony?
I'm building some simple API endpoints in Symfony using API Platform (not a fan of it, but it's already being used so don't want to re-invent the wheel).
What I'm trying to achieve is, to customize this authorize form:
enter image description here
so instead of an api key, to add a username and password fields, the swagger will send these to my custom api authentication endpoint and the returned token will be attached to the requests.
According to certain sources and chatGPT this is doable with the nelmio api doc bundle.
Here are the steps I tried so far:
installed api platform bundle
installed nelmio api doc bundle
generated secret keys
This is api_platform.yaml package config
api_platform:

    title: 'Statistics API'

    version: '2.0'

    mapping:
        paths: ['%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity']
    # Enable the Swagger documentation and export.
    enable_swagger: true

    enable_nelmio_api_doc: true

    # Enable Swagger ui.
    enable_swagger_ui: true

    # Enable the entrypoint.
    enable_entrypoint: true

    # Enable the docs.
    enable_docs: true

    collection:
        pagination:
            enabled: true
            items_per_page: 500

    formats:
          json:
              mime_types: ['application/json']
          html:
              mime_types: ['text/html']

    swagger:
        api_keys:
            apiKey:
                name: Authorization
                type: query

This is api_platform.yaml route config
api_platform_back:
    resource: .
    type: api_platform
    prefix: /api

here is the nelmio_api_doc.yaml package config
nelmio_api_doc:
    documentation:
        info:
            title: My App
            description: This is an awesome app!
            version: 1.0.0
        components:
            securitySchemes:
                bearerAuth:
                    type: http
                    scheme: bearer
                    bearerFormat: JWT
        security:
            - bearerAuth: []
    areas: # to filter documented areas
        path_patterns:
            - ^/api(?!/doc$) # Accepts routes under /api except /api/doc

nelmio_api_doc.yaml route config
# Expose your documentation as JSON swagger compliant
app.swagger:
    path: /api/doc.json
    methods: GET
    defaults: { _controller: nelmio_api_doc.controller.swagger }

## Requires the Asset component and the Twig bundle
## $ composer require twig asset
app.swagger_ui:
   path: /api
   methods: GET
   defaults: { _controller: nelmio_api_doc.controller.swagger_ui }

api firewalls from security.yaml
api:
            pattern:  ^/api
            stateless: true
            anonymous: false
            provider: app_user_provider
            jwt: ~
        api_login:
            pattern: ^/api-login
            stateless: true

and the controller method which should handle the authentication:
/**
     * @Route("/api-login", name="api_login", methods={"POST"})
     *
     * @OA\Post(
     *     path="/api-login",
     *     summary="Authenticate user and get a JWT token",
     *     tags={"Authentication"},
     *     @OA\RequestBody(
     *         required=true,
     *         @OA\JsonContent(
     *             type="object",
     *             @OA\Property(property="email", type="string"),
     *             @OA\Property(property="password", type="string")
     *         )
     *     ),
     *     @OA\Response(
     *         response=200,
     *         description="Token generated",
     *         @OA\JsonContent(
     *             type="object",
     *             @OA\Property(property="token", type="string")
     *         )
     *     ),
     *     @OA\Response(
     *         response=401,
     *         description="Invalid credentials"
     *     )
     * )
     * @Security(name="Bearer")
     */
    public function apiLogin(Request $request): JsonResponse
    {
        //some logic is in here
    }

The login endpoint works fine, if I make a request it gives the token back. But it seems that the annotation above the method has no affect at all. To be honest I'm not fully convinced that what I intend to do is really doable, because the documentation is not very clear and my changes are based on concepts suggested (but not proven) by others.
I also tried this Adding authentication documentation to Swagger in NelmioApiDocBundle and added a path property to the documentation, but nothing happened.
Any help is appreciated, thanks.
